# PyQt - how to disable scientific notation in QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt

I use the Decimal module for large numbers, but it turns into scientific notation for values less than 0.00001. Is there any way to disable this so that all decimal places are shown:

```
round(Decimal(str(value)), 9)
```

'{0:f}'.format(value) doesn't work because it shows all digits, e.g. 0.0000100000 instead of 0.00001

All I want is to show 0.000000002 after rounding 0.0000000015.

I tried

```
def set_decimals(self, value, decimals):
    val = '{0:f}'.format(Decimal(str(value)))
    rnd_value = round(Decimal(val), decimals)
    return str(rnd_value)
```

But it still converts it to scientific notation

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a better solution then this:

```
def regularNotation(value):
    """Sometimes str(decimal) makes scientific notation. This function makes the regular notation."""
    v = '{:.14f}'.format(value).rpartition('.') # 14 digits in fractional part
    return v[0] + (v[1] + v[2]).rstrip('.0') # strip trailing 0s after decimal point
```

Comment: Isn't there anything simpler to round a double number and to show all required decimal places?

Comment: @user665327, i am not sure i understand you, but put the needed number of digits in `'{:.14f}'.format(value)`. Then you don't need stripping trailing zeroes after decimal point in the last line.

Comment: If I do that, the output looks ridiculous: 0.00006660000000. I have a spinner control which I use to round down the output. So, if I have more than 5 zeros after the decimal point, I want to show it in a standard form, not scientific, nor like that above.

Comment: `regularNotation(round(Decimal(1)/Decimal(15015), 7))` -> `'0.0000666'`

Comment: regularNotation is not defined. Is it part of a Python module? Or Qt?

Comment: regularNotation is the function in the answer

Answer (score 0):

`'{0:f}'.format(value)` doesn't return what you want because the `float` type's default formatter truncates at a fixed size. This is not the case for `Decimal` itself, though:

```
>>> '{0:f}'.format(Decimal(str(0.0000000000000001)))
'0.0000000000000001'
```

By default, the format used is `'g'` of `'G'`, depending on context.